# Jetpack Compose: Reading and storing Byte array from a URL stream in a Coroutine scope

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to use the Android MLKit text recognition tool to read the text in an image from the internet.

It requires an `InputImage` object, and I want to create one using the [fromByteArray](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/InputImage#fromByteArray(byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int))
method.

I planned on opening a URL stream and reading it into a Byte array, in the code below. But I got a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` running the code.

```
@Composable
fun TweetOCR(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, screenshotModel: String) {
    val screenshot: InputImage = if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(screenshotModel)) {
        val screenshotModelByteArray = URL(screenshotModel).openStream().readBytes()
        InputImage.fromByteArray(screenshotModelByteArray, 200, 200, 0, IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12)
    } else {
        //...
    }

}
```

When I tried to use `LaunchedEffect` and `rememberCoroutineScope` to move the operation off the main thread with the below code, I had a warning that `URL` and `openStream` were "Inappropriate method blocking call" and I had the same problem as before.

```
@Composable
fun TweetOCR(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, screenshotModel: String) {
    val screenshot: InputImage = if (URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(screenshotModel)) {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        LaunchedEffect(true) {
            scope.launch {
                val screenshotModelByteArray = URL(screenshotModel).openStream().readBytes()
                InputImage.fromByteArray(screenshotModelByteArray, 200, 200, 0, IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12)
            }
        }
    } else {
        //...
    }

}
```

I don't know how else I can get this `InputImage` object without blocking the main UI thread and causing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid running the code on the main thread you can try using the following snippet instead:

```
scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val screenshotModelByteArray = URL(screenshotModel).openStream().readBytes()
    InputImage.fromByteArray(screenshotModelByteArray, 200, 200, 0, IMAGE_FORMAT_YV12)
}
```

Passing `Dispatchers.IO` into the `launch` function will take the execution off the main thread. See here for more info: https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html. Passing `Dispatchers.IO` provides a `CoroutineContext` directing [the work to be run on the IO thread](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-i-o.html?query=val%20IO:%20CoroutineDispatcher).